# Mysql with barcode reading

Tags: mysql

recently in my store i try set barcode to be scanned into php page and inserted to my mysql , all works cool .
my issue is the item i have in store have different barcode .

example
customer 1 : 32 2012brown 35  ( 32 = invoice/ 2012brown = color / 35 = size)
customer 2 : 0123   PE   41   (0123 = pallet number   PE = supplier name / 41 size )

usually i use

```
select *,
 CASE 
WHEN CODE LIKE '%2012brown%' THEN '2012'
ELSE NULL
END color ,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(CODE, ' ' ,-1) AS SIZE
 from barcode
```

but this apply only if customer1 barcode is scanned . if customer2 scanned wont apply
so my question is can i set a rule in mysql can decide weather is customer1 or 2 and proceed with condition ?
any hint would be appreciated

Comment: You can use all the logical operators available in mysql to string multiple conditions together in the `when` clause of the case statement. However, if the barcode string formats are customer specific and you have hundreds of customers then manually coding the logic into a case statement  will not work. You should not code all these properties into variable structure string. Use separate fields or json instead.

Comment: ok noted , thank you for ur replay and tips ill do more search about ur suggestion

Comment: i tried all ways i could think of i searched , but no way any other hunt would appreciate

Comment: Not sure what hint you would like to see: your logic is not sustainable. The properties should not be read from barcodes with different structures. The properties should be stored either in a predefined structure or as json (or perhaps as xml, but it is not fashionable nowadays).

Comment: ya i understand , i cant ask all customers fix 1 barcode specially for me   , i was thinking json  but videos almost i watched  is  limited to general purpose i didn't get the idea yet  maybe need more time  learn

Comment: It's not the barcode you need to fix. You need to fix how you store the data currently encoded in the barcode. You can surely ask your customers to send you the properties of their products in a pre-agreed format.